# Import __future__ division does only work if not imported from another file

Tags: python, import, division

This works: (Result = 0.01)

```
from __future__ import division

def division_test():
    print 10/1000

division_test()
```

This does not: (Result = 0)

file A:

```
from __future__ import division
```

file B:

```
from A import *

def division_test():
    print 10/1000

division_test()
```

Why? If I put things like

```
import numpy as np
```

into file A, I can import it to file B the same way and it is working all the time.

Comment: Huh.  This question is more interesting than I thought at first glance.  I think the answer is that `from __future__ import ...` is special and only affects the current module (so that someone doing an `import *` from that module will not change the behavior of their own code), but I don't know for certain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__future__` imports are not *quite* the same as others. Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#future) (emphasis mine):

> [`__future__`] allows use of the new features **on a per-module basis** before the release in which the feature becomes standard.

Comment: Hope this release will come soon. Not sure if runtime of floats takes more time, nevertheless it really should be default. Don't wanna know how much hours people have spent tearing out their hair because of this behaviour.

Comment: @user2366975 float division isn't coming to Python 2.x. Per [PEP-238](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/): *"Because of severe backwards compatibility issues... Classic division will remain the default in the Python 2.x series; true division will be standard in Python 3.0"* (which, don't forget, is nearly 6 years old now).

Comment: Oh so it is there under 3.x. Then I forgot about it... have been using 3.x a year ago but had to use 2.x for now